# How to calculate all possible combinations when in subgroups?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I am undertaking a university project in which I have to work out the average nutritional composition of a Happy Meal from McDonald's.

To do so I need to work out all the possible combinations of main, side, dip and drink with their corresponding nutritional information (see photo for layout on excel so far).

Is there a quick way of doing this-it is going to take an eternity to do manually?

[image]

Comment: Not so much with formulas as with 4 loops in vba.  You are talking 1050 combinations.

Comment: Load the ranges into Arrays and make four nested loops. There's no other magic to do that unfortunately.

Comment: You can do it with mod and offset, but quite tricky.

Comment: I really only know how to use excel basically. Any more specific advice? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Then you are going to want to find another student or friend who can take the time to write the vba, or find a pay to code site and pay someone to do it.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is an answer, you might be able to work with it. You start off by putting the numbers of choices in each section across the top and use the following formula in (say) F3 to pick out the combinations

```
=OFFSET($A$2,MOD(INT((ROW()-ROW($A$3))/PRODUCT($E$2:E$2)),F$2),0)
```

then when you pull the formula across to G3 you have to change $A$2 to $A$9 so it starts at the sides

```
=OFFSET($A$9,MOD(INT((ROW()-ROW($A$3))/PRODUCT($E$2:F$2)),G$2),0)
```

and so on then just copy all the way down to 1050 rows and do the same thing with the calories columns.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a simpler way.

[image]

Comment: any chance anyone could let me know how they worked out there would be 1050 possible combinations?

Comment: @Emily: Scott Craner was the person who mentioned the combinations possible. It was noted in your post that there would be four items in each group. There's a built-in function to handle just that. That is the COMBIN  function...  =COMBIN( number, number_ chosen). He used that, which gave an answer of 1050. "Number' was your complete list of items; "number_chosen" was your group of four items.

Comment: You're welcome! The answer is 5 X 3 X 5 X 14 - i.e. you multiply together the number of choices in each section.

Comment: A premature assumption on my part that the COMBIN function was used without looking at the layout of the data. 'Ooops".